# how to fetch id from array and pass this to next view with value according to id in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have array of items,and array contains string value and id.I want to fetch id from array on table view  row selection .If i select any row then id should pass next view class to update data for next view.
 I try but i confuse how to pass id with all data to next view for change

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [MyTableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (self.editing) {
        //Here
       //modal is my class where i create all string variable and id variable to get database value
       // here i want to pass id with next view please help here how to pass id at indexpath.row
        modal* a=(modal*)[listitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([self.lstTasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]==(NSInteger) a.Id)

        EditTask* content = [[EditTask alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditTask" bundle:nil];
        content.navigationItem.title = @"Edit Task";
        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: content]; 
        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                    initWithContentViewController:navController];
         [content release];
        [navController release];

        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                    initWithContentViewController:navController];
        _popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350, 450);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView 
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        //}
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement the following in next class viewController

```
in interface
ObjectClass* object;

- (id)initWithId:(id)object;
```

in implementation

```
- (id) initWithId:(id)object
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self)
      {
          object = [object retain];
      }
}
```

and in didSelect method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   // get the object
   nextVC* next = [[nextVC alloc] initWithId:object];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
   [next release];
 }
```

in this way u can pass any object to ur next view, this will be called before viewDidLoad of next class..

Comment: hi i want to pass my id through popover not pushviewcontroller can u help me on this

Comment: but how to pass my taskid from didselectrowatindexpath .i getting a taskid from list array what i am doing in code is write or wrong  odal* a=(modal*)[listitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([self.lstTasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]==(NSInteger) a.Id)

Comment: u write that method into EditTask and modify this
EditTask* next = [[EditTask alloc] initWithId:object];

Comment: i am  right in taking id from array Tasksmodal* a=(Tasksmodal*)[self.lstTasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];or i try this also but not working  if ([self.lstTasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]==(NSInteger) taskobject.TaskId)please help me

Comment: and 1 more thing in ur code u have alloc & initialize popOver twice, delete 1 of the statements.. wat output u r getting..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6992/discussion-between-rocky-and-vishy)

Comment: can u help me on simple way how to take id from array please see my code i am doing right to take id from array in indexpath row